# Passing Type information to MongoDB so it can deserialize interface types properly?

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have a class that I serialize into MongoDB as a `BsonDocument`, this class also happens to have a property of type `IMyInterface`.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public IMyInterface IntRef { get; set; }
}
```

During a `MyClass` object instances lifetime `IntRef` can reference multiple different classes that implement `IMyInterface`. Upon serialization I have found that all of the data from the class that `IntRef` points to is also serialized in the `BsonDocument`, not just `Name`.

Upon deserialization though `BsonDocument.Deserialize` does not have information about the `Type` of the class that `IntRef` points to and throws an exception. **How can I provide the `Type` information to my call to `Deserialize`?**

I also have a naive work around where I `Deserialize` the part of the document that is `IntRef`, which works well. Given the proper class `Type`,  `BsonDocument.Deserialize` returns the object instance of that `Type`. Though the issue here is that I still cannot `Deserialize` the top level `BsonDocument` representing `MyClass` because it still holds the sub document pertaining to `IntRef`. **Is there a way to tell `Deserialize` to ignore part of `BsonDocument`?** *I had the idea to just setting `MyBsonDocument[SubDocName] = null` though its non-nullable.*

Comment: I have limited experience myself with Mongo and BsonDocument, but since you've had no responses, did you see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241788/ignoring-properties-inside-composite-property-with-bsonignore)?

Comment: Hmm. Its close I guess, though this is to not serialize some part of an object, not to not deserialize it. Though... I think the `ClassMap` might be part of the answer. I will have to look into it, I have never seen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of `MyClass` pointing to an interface type, which could then hold any class' Bson that implements that interface, we have to tell MongoDB the type of class' that can at the end of that (all of the) interface. It can then infer from the classes that it knows of how to deserialize certain `BsonDocuments` containing those class' Bson.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyIntImpl : IMyInterface
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public IMyInterface IntRef { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        IntRef = new MyIntImpl();
    }
}

// When starting up MongoDB
private void RegisterClasses()
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyIntImpl>();
}
```

By adding the class `MyIntImpl` to the BsonClassMap it now knows how to deserialize Bson from that class type. You just have to make sure you keep the map filled with classes that implement interfaces you might serialize.

Some reference links: [High to low level overview of C# MongoDB serialization](https://darkiri.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/bson-serialization-with-mongodb-c-driver/), [an SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954879/serialize-deserialize-mongodb-bson-document-using-official-c-sharp-driver) that outlines the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this post did not work for me.

After going round in circles with this for a while I found this gem which allows you to easily specify the type from which the interface should be derived - it uses the `ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer` (MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers):

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer<IMyClass, MyClass>))]
public IMyClass SomeProperty { get; set; }
```